# How can I reduce the 1s consumer lag in the Kafka Tutorial?

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm working through the very first section of the Confluent  Tutorials: https://kafka-tutorials.confluent.io/kafka-console-consumer-producer-basics/kafka.html. Everything works as described, but I notice there's about 1 second of lag between when I press enter in the producer terminal and when a message is displayed in the consumer terminal. Is it the producer or the consumer who's responsible for this lag/batching? Is there a way to configure things to be more responsive? A quick search turned up the `linger.ms` setting, but it seems like recent versions of Kafka default this setting to zero, and it doesn't appear to be overridden in these containers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it looks like setting `--timeout=0` in the producer makes the lag disappear. Looking at the [`kafka-console-producer` source code](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/2.5.0/core/src/main/scala/kafka/tools/ConsoleProducer.scala#L99-L100), `--timeout` defaults to 1000 and gets merged into `LINGER_MS_CONFIG`. So even though linger defaults to zero in Kafka generally, it effectively defaults to 1 sec in this command line producer.